# Why NsightVSE Analyzer didn't work on RTX 2080ti?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nsight

[U can see the picture for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvLQq.png)

The project can run correctly both on Titan Xp and RTX 2080ti.
And I can get the information of Titan Xp,but when I use RTX 2080ti,the situation in this picture emerged.I've tried both on VS2015 and VS2017 with cuda10 which include Nsight6.0.

Comment: It's a cuda program.It seems that Nsight can't help me get the information of kernel lanuching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NsightVSE Analysis Trace 
Supports Kepler, Maxwell, and Pascal GPUs.
For Pascal and later GPUs (including RTX / Turing GPUs), see Nsight Systems or Visual Profiler

NsightVSE Analysis Profiling on Turing GPUs
is available for Volta and later GPUs (including RTX / Turing GPUs) when using the Nsight Compute profiler.
NOTE that Nsight Compute is also available as a stand-alone and CLI profiler

- Nsight Systems : https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-systems
- Nsight Compute : https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-compute
- Visual Profiler: https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-visual-profiler

Comment: The project can run correctly when I use interaction profile in Nsight Compute,but when I switch to non-interaction profile,it shows in command window that  "==PROF== Profiling - 1: Fatal Python error Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams LookupError: unknown encoding: cp936".I toatally don't understand why! Can you help?